# Streaming Server Network Performance

Tags: linux, networking, centos, performance, streaming

I have server Linux based on

```
centos 6.5 final 64bit , 
ram 128 G.B 
dual E5-2650 processor 
Hard disk : 4 SSD Hard disk RAID-5
Network Speed 1/Gbps
Bandwidth Speed 500/Mbps up to 3/Gbps
```

My Wbebserv apache based on nginx engine

I have Problem playing videos on the server , the server play videos after 12 Seconds , i want to increase the performance so the videos load less than 5 Seconds

What is the best configuration i have to do in nginx , and sysctl configuration or other configurations so i can increase the bandwidth playing speed ?

Comment: @TheCleaner it's not duplicated , because i want to know the values i should set in the configuration files so i can had the best perforamnce for playing videos to the server , this link show u information generally

Comment: I voted that way instead of **too broad/book answer** to at least give you some things to start down.  Your question isn't specific enough.  We don't know your server config, nginx config, webserver stats, performance metrics, etc.

Comment: @TheCleaner i actually don't know what is the configuration REALTED to slow playing videos issue so i can put the configuration to see it

Comment: @user209827 ... well if you don't know, how/why do you expect us to be able to divine the answer for you?  We're not clairvoyant.

Comment: it's really nice to see u all mark the question as duplicated instead of telling the answer because with all do respect you guys mark questions duplicated , closed that u cannot HAVE the answer , and if my question not clear how could ewwhite answer it ? and how could u guys moderators in this site ?

Comment: @user209827 They're not moderators, they're normal users. See http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/

Comment: The answer from Ed is a very generic answer that he's used before - perhaps we should search his answers and close this as a dupe of that.

Comment: @iain Awwwwww :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do to your base system:

```
# yum install tuned tuned-utils
# tuned-adm profile throughput-performance
```

See the chart below. These settings will at least make the I/O scheduler aware of what you're *trying* to do and help with some better sysctl and storage subsystem defaults. Can you test with this and report back? You can revert the settings to default with `tuned-adm profile default`

[image]